# Re-mapping rdf data expressively

Tags: xml, xslt, rdf, sparql, owl

I'm fairly new to the triples data format, so this question is kind of noobish.
Is there an expressive syntax which allows me to expressively declare (I.e. using xml, xslt etc.) a  transformation of one representation of a graph to another.
For example: I have a graph representing a book store in which the subjects are all :Series which contain a list of books in the series. I want to re-map that representation into a bookstore with :Book subjects which have a predicate :Series.
The mapping should support many to many mappings. That is, one entity on the source store could be mapped to many in the target and vice versa.
It would also be best to be able to supply conversions on the values themselves (regex matching, date format normalization etc.)

Of course I could manufactor a complicated SPARQL query that does these things but we eventually want to have hundreds of these conversions so we want an expressive syntax that is human readable. Preferably without having to manufactor the syntax and parser ourselves.

Comment: You mention them, but I'd suggest that you do take a look at the SPARQL options.  With SPARQL you get to write the graph pattern that you want to match in a very concise way, and you construct the results you want just as easily.  With SPARQL 1.1's INSERT/DELETE combinations, you can run the query one one graph and store the results in another.  I think you'll be hard pressed to find another format that lets you describe your input and output so concisely.  If you can give a specific example of input and the output you'd like, we could show the corresponding SPARQL transformation.

Comment: @joshua I believe I am actually able to construct the SPARQL queries myself. I am looking for a declerative language syntax that builds the queries for me since I will have hundreds of such mappings to perform. Basically something similar to xslt or xml schemas for rdf

Answer (score 2):

If you want something even higher-level than SPARQL INSERT/DELETE, perhaps SPIN RDF might suit your needs: http://spinrdf.org/

In particular, SPIN Templates http://composing-the-semantic-web.blogspot.co.uk/2009/01/understanding-spin-templates.html